# "Blood circulation". Why blood bleeds in atmosphere ?

Tags: blood-circulation

If our body's blood pressure is 120 mm-Hg then why blood goes out of our body in 760 mm -Hg pressure if we have cuts?

Comment: In your example the blood pressure is  actually 120 + 760 = 880 mm Hg. So , higher than atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 6):

That's actually the gauge pressure that we measure. Gauge pressure is the amount by which the pressure measured in a fluid exceeds that of the atmosphere. So, when we say that our blood pressure is 180mmhg, it's wrong. In reality, the blood pressure is (180+760)mmHg inside the blood vessel, and our blood pressure exceeds atmospheric pressure by 180mmhg.